# I couldn't float my image to the right without it overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have multiple images that need to float to the bottom right of each "entry" without overlapping the next "entry":

```css
.body {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-image: url(images/background.gif);
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

#top {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.good {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: orange;
  border-width: 2px;
}

.entry {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(196, 226, 255);
}

.date {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: purple;
  border-width: 2px;
}

p {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 2px;
}

#footer {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  border-width: 3px;
  background-color: white;
}

.entry img {
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <h1> Eating Journal </h1>
  <h2 class="good"> Good things to eat and where to find them </h2>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <h2><span class="date">09/06/201</span>: Dosa </h2>
  <p>
    Dosas are a favorite in India. They are made from a chickpea and rice batter that is fried on a griddle. In India these are very cheap . . unfortunately, they will cost you in Toronto.
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="images/dosa.jpg" alt="The Dosa">
  </p>
  <p>
    If you like Indian food, check out <a target="_blank" href="http://http://karaikudi.ca/order-online/">Karaikudi</a> in Scarborough.
  </p>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <h2><span class="date"> 08/24/2017</span>: Pide </h2>
  <p>
    If you haven't tried <em> Pide </em>, also known as Turkish Pizza, your life is not complete.
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="images/pide.jpg" alt="Pide - turkish pizza">
  </p>
  <p>
    My current favorite Pide Restaurant, is <a target="_blank" href="http://mrpide.ca/">Mr. Pide</a> in Greektown, Toronto. Order the <strong> Lahmacun </strong>!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <h2> <span class="date">08/22/2017</span>: Falafel </h2>
  <p>
    One reason to wake up every morning -- Falafels!
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="images/falafel.jpg" alt="Falafel!">
  </p>
  <p> If you like falafels, check out <a href="http://alibabas.ca/">Ali Baba's</a>. They have two for the price of one falafel sandwiches on Tuesdays!
  </p>
</div>

<div class="entry">
  <h2><span class="date"> 07/10/2017</span>: Spicy Pot </h2>
  <p> Ma la xiang guo is a dish from the Sichuan/Chongqing region of China. You can select a number of different items that are cooked together. This dish uses a special numbing spice (ma) together with spicy chilli (la) cooked until fragrant (xiang) in a
    big pot (guo). </p>
  <p>
    <img src="images/malaxiangguo.jpg" alt="Malaxiangguo">
  </p>
  <p> Unfortunately, I haven't found a good restaturant in Toronto that serves this. You can make it at home using with this <a target="_blank" href="http://www.noobcook.com/mala-xiang-guo/">recipe</a>. </p>
</div>

<div id="footer">
  <p> (c) Author of the Eating Journal - Abdel Zhang </p>
</div>
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: actual]

And this is how I want it to look:

[image: expected]

Thank you to anyone the can help me!

Comment: You can't `float` "bottom / right".

Comment: I couldn;t find the answer on the thread

Comment: That's because there isn't one..essentially.

Comment: think you can help me?

Comment: No, sorry...you just can't do this. That's not the way text flows.